# How do I circumvent this error: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED]

Tags: ssl

I am using VSCode and python 3.11.4 to get api data using the urllib.request module and urlopen function, but get the above error.

My code:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
 
url = 'https://www.example.com/api/ect...'
response = urlopen(url)
```

At this point I get the error:

```
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: certificate has expired (_ssl.c:1002)>
```

How can I fix or circumvent this? I am not working with sensitive data. Thank you.

Comment: Look like the certificate has expired.

Comment: (1) have the server admins fix their server (2) since the data isn't sensitive, use HTTP and not HTTPS (3) move to Gallifrey, become a Time Lord, get a TARDIS, and travel back in time to when the certificate was valid -- to see when to target, do `openssl s_client -connect host:443 </dev/null | openssl x509 -noout -dates` (on Windows use `<NUL:`; if using old OpenSSL below 1.1.1 add `-servername host` to the left part) but the TARDIS often goes to the wrong millennium or planet/galaxy/whatever anyway